# how to create bunch of databases in beeline by using shell script dynamically?

Tags: linux, shell, hive, beeline

How to Create The  bunch of Databases in Beeline using shell script by passing variables ?

I Have of list databases like abc,abcd,abcd3,abcd4 now i want to create this databases using shell script by passing variables?

Answer (score 0):

```
# define all database names in an array
dbs=(abcd abcd1 abcd2 abcd3)

# iterate over an array
for db in "${dbs[@]}"
do
   beeline -u <HIVE_SERVER2_URL> -n <username> -p <password> -e "create database $db"
done
```

Create a shell script with above code and replaces value for database url, username and password in beeline command and it should create database with the names in defined array

Alternatively if you have password stored in file then you can pass password file as well in beeline command.
ex. `beeline -u jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default -n jainik -w password_file`

Comment: hi jainik ,thanks for the help but im getting following errors when i tried to run this script .

Comment: dbs = (test3 test4)

# iterate over an array
for db in "${dbs[@]}"
do
   beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://devhcdl2.azure.ril.com:2181,devhcdl4.azure.ril.com:2181,devhcdl3.azure.ril.com:2181/;serviceDiscoveryMode=zooKeeper;zooKeeperNamespace=hiveserver2"  -e "create database $db"

done

Comment: tse.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
tse.sh: line 2: `dbs = (test3 test4)'

Comment: Oh I see why it's complaining, it's a space issue, I mistyped in an array declaration. Just updated an answer. please change `dbs = (test3 test4)` to `dbs=(test3 test4)`. No space before and after '='